# eslint pre-commiot on git

Tags: javascript, git, eslint

how i can run in the pre commit script eslint on the files in the add stage?

I have in the hooks folder the .eslintrc file.

I have also the script:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# An example hook script to verify what is about to be committed.
# Called by "git commit" with no arguments.  The hook should
# exit with non-zero status after issuing an appropriate message if
# it wants to stop the commit.
#
# To enable this hook, rename this file to "pre-commit".

function lintit () {
  a=("${(f)$(git diff --name-only | grep -E '(.js)$')}")
  e=$(eslint -c eslint.json $a)
  echo $e
  if [[ "$e" != *"0 problems"* ]]; then
    echo "ERROR: Check eslint hints."
    exit 1 # reject
  fi
}
lintit
```

but it doesn't do the eslint i have in the .eslintc file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see two (possible) issues with your script:

- The file might not have executable flags set
- Your sub shell expression is wrong

Git won't execute unless it has proper executable flags on unixoid systems.

```
$ chmod ug+x .git/hooks/pre-commit
```

If you haven't seen any error message yet, it's probably due to this.

But, however this is not correct, it's a syntax error:

```
a=("${(f)$(git diff --name-only | grep -E '(.js)$')}")
e=$(eslint -c eslint.json $a)
```

Better:

```
a="$( git diff --name-only | grep -E '(.js)$' )"
e=$( eslint -c eslint.json $a )
```

---

### Futher improvements

#### Simplify the result check

eslint will exit with a negative (non-zero) exit code if it has found an error.

```
eslint ${ESLINT_CONF} $( ... )
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "eslint is unhappy."
    exit 1
fi
```

If no `echo` is required it would be enough to have the `eslint` statement at the last line, so the shell will exit with that command's exit code.

But, the downside of using the exit code is, that, since eslint does exit with a positive code (zero) on warnings, you won't be able to detect warnings. In that case you still have to match for warnings.

#### Check not only for modified files

Your `git diff` expression won't find new files. You may want to use `git status` instead:

```
git status --porcelain | awk '{print $2}'  | grep -E '(.js)$'
```

---

### Final script

```
#!/bin/sh

ESLINT_CONF=".eslintrc.json"

eslint ${ESLINT_CONF} $( git status --porcelain | awk '{print $2}' | grep -E '(.js)$' ) >/dev/null
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "ERROR: Check eslint hints."
    exit 1
fi

exit 0
```

Or, simplified ...

```
#!/bin/sh

ESLINT_CONF=".eslintrc.json"

eslint ${ESLINT_CONF} $( git status --porcelain | awk '{print $2}' | grep -E '(.js)$' ) >/dev/null
```

Or, with check for warnings ...

```
#!/bin/sh

ESLINT_CONF=".eslintrc.json"

RES="( eslint ${ESLINT_CONF} $( git status --porcelain | awk '{print $2}' | grep -E '(.js)$' ) )"

if [ $? -ne 0 ] || [[ "${RES}" != *"0 warning"* ]]; then
    echo "ERROR: Check eslint hints."
    exit 1
fi
```

Remove `>/dev/null` (script 1 and 2) or `echo "${RES}"` (script 3) to show the output of eslint.

Comment: For the final script u wrote, how i can see in the command line the warnings?

Comment: Remove `>/dev/null` (1 and 2) or `echo "${RES}"` (3)

Comment: Hi, i add in the final script `echo "${RES}"`, and i get: `ERROR: Check eslint hints.
( eslint .eslintrc.json src/sap/rules/ui/ExpressionEditor.js )`, why is that?

Comment: Hi, its work after i remove `${ESLINT_CONF}` and had `$'`: `ESLINT_CONF=".eslintrc.json"

RES="$( eslint $( git status --porcelain | awk '{print $2}' | grep -E '(.js)$' ) )"

if [ $? -ne 0 ] || [[ "${RES}" != *"0 warning"* ]]; then
    echo "ERROR: Check eslint hints."
 echo "${RES}"
    exit 1
fi`